# Does speed of convergence of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem imply Holder Continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Given a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$, suppose that

$$
\Big|\frac{1}{\text{vol}(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)} f(z)dz -f(x) \Big| \le C r^\alpha
$$
uniformly over $x \in K$ some bounded domain of $\mathbb R^d$  for some $C>0,\alpha \in (0,1) $. Do we have that $f \in C^\alpha(K)$? The converse is simple to get, but I could not prove whether this is true.

Comment: Interesting question. All I know so far is it's false for $\alpha=1$ (because any "Zygmund function" satisfies the hypothesis for $\alpha=1$,)

Comment: If you take the absolute value inside the integral, i.e., assume $\int_{B(x,r)}|f(z)-f(x)|\,dz\leq C r^{n+\alpha}$ this is true (see *Mean Oscillation Over Cubes and Hölder Continuity* by Norman Meyers). I would expect it to fail if you take the absolute value outside the integral, although I don't have a counterexample at the moment.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you very much for the reference, it led me to find the notion of Morrey spaces which is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kernel I was pretty sure I had seen this kind of expressions before in relation with some function spaces, but I couldn't remember which ones. Thanks for letting me know that they are Morrey spaces.