# Confusion with the mean value theorem for integration of vector-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth function.

Then, I wonder if the following limit exists as $n \to \infty$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{n^2}{Vol[B(y,1/n)]}\int_{B(y,1/n)}[f(x) \cdot f(x)-f(y)\cdot f(y)]d^Nx
\end{equation}

Here, $B(y,1/n)$ is the closed ball centere at some fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with radius $1/n$ and $Vol[B(y,1/n)$ is its $N-$dimensional volume. Also, $f(x) \cdot f(x)$ is the Euclidean dot product.

What comes to mind is something like second order derivative of $f$ at $y$, but it seems so complicated...I am aware that the L'Hospital rule does not apply for higher dimensions..

More concretely, what about we take $f(x)=x$?

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What has this to do with the mean value theorem?

Comment: This is essentially asking for the rates of convergence for the Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Comment: Oh I thought it is like L'Hospital theorem or something like that... Could you provide more insight? I am totally puzzled....

Comment: I guess I will need the operator norm of the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263207/does-speed-of-convergence-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-imply-holder-conti) question is related.

Comment: This is related to one definition of $\operatorname{div} g$ with $g=\|f\|^2$. Note that due to symmetry of the integration domain $g(x+v)-g(x)$ can be replaced by $\frac12(g(x+v)-2g(x)+g(x-v)=\frac12g''(x)[v,v]+O(\|v\|^4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for $f:x\mapsto x$. I do not know how to answer the question in general, but here is the answer in particular for the identity function:

---

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Stated differently, you're looking at: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(N/2)!}{\pi^{N/2}}\cdot n^{2+N}\int_{B(y,1/n)}(\|f(x)\|^2-\|f(y)\|^2)\d\lambda(x)$$Where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue $N$-measure for some $N\in\Bbb N$.

Let's examine, for simplicity's sake, what happens when $f=\mathrm{Id}$ and $y=0$. We have (I don't pretend to understand the theorem, having never seen its proof, but I use the [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula)): $$\int_{B(y,1/n)}\|x\|^2\d\lambda(x)=\int_0^{1/n}r^2\d r\cdot(2\pi/n)\cdot\frac{(\pi/n^2)^{\frac{N}{2}-1}}{\left(\frac{N}{2}-1\right)!}=\frac{2\cdot\pi^{N/2}}{3\cdot\left(\frac{N}{2}-1\right)!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{N+2}}$$

So we're looking at: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(N/2)!}{\pi^{N/2}}\cdot n^{2+N}\cdot\frac{2\pi^{N/2}}{3\left(\frac{N}{2}-1\right)!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{N+2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{N}{3}=\frac{N}{3}$$

In fact, for any fixed $n\in\Bbb N$, the expression evaluates to $N/3$.

To be clear, the coarea formula is used to justify integration by spherical coordinates (and note that $x\mapsto\|x\|^2$ is constant on each sphere about the origin).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can use this directly, but it may provide some insight. There is a version of the mean value theorem for Banach-valued functions, cf. Diestel and Uhl *Vector Measures*:

**Corollary 8. (page 48)**
Let $f$ be Bochner integrable with respect to $\mu$. Then for each $E\in \Sigma$ with $\mu(E)>0$ one has
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\mu(E)} 
\int_E
f
\ d\mu
\end{equation}
is in the closed convex hull of $f(E)$.